# Rearrange the UI

Tags: ragnarok-online-2

Is there any way to rearrange the UI, outside from the three set layouts that are provided?

I find that some elements, such as the acolyte holy water charge bar, are very poorly positioned.  Are there mods that allow manipulation of the UI?

Answer (score 1):

As of `2013 May 13`, the only GUI elements that can be ***moved*** are:

- **The chat window:** This is done by clicking on the button in the upper-left corner of the window and dragging your mouse around
- **The map:** This is done by clicking on the upper window border where "*World Map*" is written and dragging your mouse around. When the map is in transparent mode, you can temporarily display the window border by pressing `Ctrl`
- **The bags and all other openable windows, except for the `Esc`-menu:** This is done the same way as with the map; by clicking on the upper window border where the window title is written and dragging your mouse around.

Keep in mind, that the only GUI element that will keep its user-defined position is the **map**. The chat window, for instance, will reset its position as soon as the loading screen appears (upon entering a dungeon, or changing a map)

You can not move or change any other GUI elements

The only GUI element that can be ***resized*** is:

- **The chat window:** This can be done either by clicking the button in the upper-right corner of the window, to resize the window to one out of 4 predefined sizes, or by clicking and dragging somewhere below the **Channel** and the **Create Chatting Room** buttons. Your mouse cursor must look like this:
  [image: Screenshot]

Keep in mind, that by changing the character, logging out, or exiting the game, the chat window will be reset to its default size.